# Wordpress и Server Sent Events

Tags: wordpress, hook, sse

Хочу сделать автообновление контента на странице через SSE.

Сделал php файлик, в нем все OK, данные отправляются, с js тоже все OK - клиент подключается, данные получает. Но хочу это все дело повесить на хук `save_post` WordPress, чтобы при сохранении поста  сервер отсылал клиенту данные, а именно данные этого самого поста. Не могу сообразить, как это сделать(

Может кто-то подскажет что-то?

Спасибо большое!

Comment: https://github.com/hoaproject/Eventsource

Comment: Смотрю на библиотеку, но не могу понять чем она мне может помочь) У меня работает sse, с этим все ок. Мне надо повесить отправку данных при срабатывании события save_post - с этим сложности

Comment: Из вопроса было не очень понятно, как именно идет отправка - через SSE или ещё нет. Также непонятно, как вы запускаете этот ваш файлик php - он связан с ядром или нет? Кроме того, непонятно - вы какое сохранение поста хотите отслеживать - произведённого данным пользователем, у которого сессия SSE или нет? Если ответ на один из этих вопросов - нет - то никак к хуку не подключиться, надо мониторить базу (делать туда запросы с каким-то интервалом).

Comment: у меня стоит автопостинг с помощью wp_insert_post через curl. Задача такая, что когда происходит добавление поста в бд - сразу же отображать этот пост на сайте, без перезагрузки страницы. Есть js, который подгружается пользователю и он слушает канал sse, мне надо как-то событие создание поста и сам пост отправить в канал sse(пользователям которые слушают этот стрим),чтобы показать пользователю на странице новодобавленый пост. Как-то так))

Comment: Есть хук save_post, как вы правильно заметили, подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/save_post). Если вы сможете из этого хука отправить сообщение в канал SSE - задача решена. Но насколько я понимаю, событие insert_post и save_post возникают в одном php-процессе, а SSE-канал открыт в другом. И как между двумя процессами php организовать связь, я не понимаю. Разве что файл, база, или разделяемый кеш в Redis, например.

Comment: Вы правильно написали - в разных местах и если я смогу из этого хука отправить сообщение в канал SSE - задача решена)) Но пока не могу сообразить как это сделать((( Может тут кто-то поможет

Comment: Ещё раз - если это в разных php-процессах (а, похоже, что так)  - то напрямую невозможно. Только файл, база, кеш Redis.